# Javascript function is not available on page refresh

Tags: javascript

```
function set_current_language(lang){
    var arrLang = [{code:"zh-hant",url:"http://dev2.next.tv?lang=zh-hant"},{code:"zh-hans",url:"http://dev2.next.tv?lang=zh-hans"},{code:"en",url:"http://dev2.next.tv"}];
    var lang_count = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < lang_count; i++) {
        if( lang == arrLang[i].code ){
            window.location.assign(arrLang[i].url);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I call this function to reload page with query parameter. **It works only once**. **2nd time** it **does not** reach my break point in the function. But the function is available in `inspect element window`.

Comment: is the for loop getting executed? try using a debugger in your browser.

Comment: I have added a debug point to for loop. First time it executes and refresh the page. But not second time. It is not coming to my debug point.

Comment: Where is it getting stuck?

Comment: I am sorry. It wasn't a fault of the function. The object array wasn't generating when the language is changed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. It wasn't a fault of the function. The object array wasn't generating when the language is changed.